# How to plot the name of a line on a legend without using color, linetype or shape

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this plot I want to show on the legend the name ("c") of the red solid line. How can I do it since that line must be of 'red' color, be 'solid' and have no 'point shape'?

How can I show in that situation the name of the 'c' line on a legend?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(line_label = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
             year = c(2010, 2012, 2010, 2012),
             value = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
df2 <- tibble(line_label = c('c', 'c'),
              year = c(2010, 2012),
              value = c(0.15, 0.35))

p <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = line_label), size = 1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed"),
                        guide = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = line_label, color = line_label), size = 2) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = year, y = value),
            alpha = .8, size = 2, color = "#DA2537") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#BFBFBF", "#173C70")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2010, 2012, by = 1)) 
plot(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You can add `scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "blue", linetype = "dashed")))`, but I'm not sure whether this is what you are looking for?

Comment: or say if you want to have orange for line color, add +scale_color_manual(values="orange") to the plot..

Comment: but from where can I get the line name? In my "real" case I have 2 geom_lines in the same ggplot. It is the second one that has no name because I defined the color, linetype and shape of that line before.

Comment: Please update the example to better reflect your use case and clarify what your expected output is.

Comment: Why not combine your data, use a single `geom_line` layer, and the default legend will be correct?

Comment: @Gregor That is a possible solution, but how can I after that format in a special way (color, size, linetype, shapepoint) that particular line?

Comment: The same way you normally would... map (color, size, linetype, shapepoint) inside `aes()`. You can either (a) map it to `line_label` and set the scale values so that the first two are the same and the third one is different, or (b) map it to a new column in your data, call it something like `is_special`, set it to "yes" for the special line "c" and "no" otherwise. And then use the scales like normal.

Comment: @Gregor I created the third column as you said in (b) but I don't know how to use it. As `group = is_special` inside `aes`? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using the `is_special` column idea.

```
df_all = rbind(df1, df2)
df_all$is_special = ifelse(df_all$line_label == "c", "y", "n")

ggplot(data = df_all, aes(x = year, y = value, color = line_label)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = line_label, size = is_special, alpha = is_special)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = line_label), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#BFBFBF", "#173C70", "#DA2537")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed", "solid")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c("n" = 1, "y" = 2), guide = "none") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("n" = 1, "y" = 0.8), guide = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2010, 2012, by = 1))
```

[image]